# Simple Windows web form application to asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, label, buttonclick

I have simple application in C# windows web form (designed in Visual C# 2010 Express).

Just 3 buttons, and 3 labels - when I click button 2 I have number of day in int (from 0 to 6) and then I switch this number to correct name of a day in label. Also when I click button 1 or 3 I have +1 or -1 day in all labels.

Here is an example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                                              
    {

        NumberDay--; 
        if (NumberDay < 0) NumberDay = 6; 
        switch (NumberDay)
        {
            case 0:
                label1.Text = "Saturday";                               
                label2.Text = "Sunday";
                label3.Text = "Monday";
                break;
            case 1:
                label1.Text = "Sunday";
                label2.Text = "Monday";
                label3.Text = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 2:
                label1.Text = " Monday";
                label2.Text = "Tuesday";
                label3.Text = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                label1.Text = "Tuesday";
                label2.Text = "Wednesday";
                label3.Text = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 4:
                label1.Text = "Wednesday";
                label2.Text = "Thursday";
                label3.Text = "Friday";
                break;
            case 5:
                label1.Text =  "Thursday";
                label2.Text =  "Friday";
                label3.Text = "Saturday";
                break;
            case 6:
                label1.Text = "Friday";
                label2.Text = "Saturday";
                label3.Text = "Sunday";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = button3.Enabled = true; 
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;                                     
        NumberDay = (int)today.DayOfWeek;                             

        switch (NumerDnia)
        {
            case 0:
                label1.Text = "Saturday";                               
                label2.Text = "Sunday";
                label3.Text = "Monday";
                break;
            case 1:
                label1.Text = "Sunday";
                label2.Text = "Monday";
                label3.Text = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 2:
                label1.Text = " Monday";
                label2.Text = "Tuesday";
                label3.Text = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                label1.Text = "Tuesday";
                label2.Text = "Wednesday";
                label3.Text = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 4:
                label1.Text = "Wednesday";
                label2.Text = "Thursday";
                label3.Text = "Friday";
                break;
            case 5:
                label1.Text =  "Thursday";
                label2.Text =  "Friday";
                label3.Text = "Saturday";
                break;
            case 6:
                label1.Text = "Friday";
                label2.Text = "Saturday";
                label3.Text = "Sunday";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        NumberDay++; 
        if (NumberDay > 6) NumberDay = 0; 
        switch (NumberDay)
        {
            case 0:
                label1.Text = "Saturday";                               
                label2.Text = "Sunday";
                label3.Text = "Monday";
                break;
            case 1:
                label1.Text = "Sunday";
                label2.Text = "Monday";
                label3.Text = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 2:
                label1.Text = " Monday";
                label2.Text = "Tuesday";
                label3.Text = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                label1.Text = "Tuesday";
                label2.Text = "Wednesday";
                label3.Text = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 4:
                label1.Text = "Wednesday";
                label2.Text = "Thursday";
                label3.Text = "Friday";
                break;
            case 5:
                label1.Text =  "Thursday";
                label2.Text =  "Friday";
                label3.Text = "Saturday";
                break;
            case 6:
                label1.Text = "Friday";
                label2.Text = "Saturday";
                label3.Text = "Sunday";
                break;
        }
    }
```

In normal C# app it all works. When I try do the same in asp.net (Visual Express 2012 for Veb) I have some trouble:

1. When I click button 2 it's all good. When I press button 1/3 ONCE I have wrong day in all label (or when I press nothing is happening)
2. When I press the button couple more times nothing happen - page isn't reloading (?) in every button click, label isn't changing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: is NumberDay is a page level static varible?

Comment: You are new in Asp.net so first google basics of Asp.net. Asp.net and Windows application are totaly diffrent in term of State

Comment: @user2456849: Please provide the ASPX code as well so that we can surely help you out.

Comment: int NumberDay is declared before protected void Page_Load

Comment: In asp.net NumberDay get reset in every post back

Answer (score 0):

If you have just declared your variable "NumberDay" in page level like this

```
int NumberDay;
```

that is why its not maintaining its value because NumberDay get reset in every post back. you can do it using ViewState like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                                              
{

    NumberDay = ViewState["VS_NumberDay"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["VS_NumberDay"]) : 0;
    NumberDay--;         

    if (NumberDay < 0) NumberDay = 6; 

    ViewState["VS_NumberDay"] = NumberDay;

    switch (NumberDay)
    {
        case 0:
            label1.Text = "Saturday";                               
            label2.Text = "Sunday";
            label3.Text = "Monday";
            break;
        case 1:
            label1.Text = "Sunday";
            label2.Text = "Monday";
            label3.Text = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 2:
            label1.Text = " Monday";
            label2.Text = "Tuesday";
            label3.Text = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            label1.Text = "Tuesday";
            label2.Text = "Wednesday";
            label3.Text = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 4:
            label1.Text = "Wednesday";
            label2.Text = "Thursday";
            label3.Text = "Friday";
            break;
        case 5:
            label1.Text =  "Thursday";
            label2.Text =  "Friday";
            label3.Text = "Saturday";
            break;
        case 6:
            label1.Text = "Friday";
            label2.Text = "Saturday";
            label3.Text = "Sunday";
            break;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = button3.Enabled = true; 
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;                                     
    NumberDay = (int)today.DayOfWeek;                             
    ViewState["VS_NumberDay"] = NumberDay;
    switch (NumerDnia)
    {
        case 0:
            label1.Text = "Saturday";                               
            label2.Text = "Sunday";
            label3.Text = "Monday";
            break;
        case 1:
            label1.Text = "Sunday";
            label2.Text = "Monday";
            label3.Text = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 2:
            label1.Text = " Monday";
            label2.Text = "Tuesday";
            label3.Text = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            label1.Text = "Tuesday";
            label2.Text = "Wednesday";
            label3.Text = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 4:
            label1.Text = "Wednesday";
            label2.Text = "Thursday";
            label3.Text = "Friday";
            break;
        case 5:
            label1.Text =  "Thursday";
            label2.Text =  "Friday";
            label3.Text = "Saturday";
            break;
        case 6:
            label1.Text = "Friday";
            label2.Text = "Saturday";
            label3.Text = "Sunday";
            break;
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    NumberDay = ViewState["VS_NumberDay"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["VS_NumberDay"]) : 0;
    NumberDay++;         
    if (NumberDay > 6) NumberDay = 0; 

    ViewState["VS_NumberDay"] = NumberDay;

    switch (NumberDay)
    {
        case 0:
            label1.Text = "Saturday";                               
            label2.Text = "Sunday";
            label3.Text = "Monday";
            break;
        case 1:
            label1.Text = "Sunday";
            label2.Text = "Monday";
            label3.Text = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 2:
            label1.Text = " Monday";
            label2.Text = "Tuesday";
            label3.Text = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            label1.Text = "Tuesday";
            label2.Text = "Wednesday";
            label3.Text = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 4:
            label1.Text = "Wednesday";
            label2.Text = "Thursday";
            label3.Text = "Friday";
            break;
        case 5:
            label1.Text =  "Thursday";
            label2.Text =  "Friday";
            label3.Text = "Saturday";
            break;
        case 6:
            label1.Text = "Friday";
            label2.Text = "Saturday";
            label3.Text = "Sunday";
            break;
    }
}
```